# Is activity running

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I've a little problem in my "timer" development. 
I've an activity that shows a timer and when the user press start it schedules an alarm with AlarmManager service. 
In the broadcast receiver I want to check if the activity Timer is running and visible in order to avoid unneeded notification.
So the broadcast receiver should set notification only if the activity isn't in foreground.
Any suggestion?

Thx,
SL3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Singletone pattern or SharedPreference property and store there some kind of state.

So, from your activity you can write the state and from your broadcast receiver you can read that state and then decide what to do.

Comment: It works like a charm. Sometimes simplicity is all that we need. Thank you very much.